# HAML - how do I create this line of HTML

Tags: haml

This is kind of a complicated line of HTML to create in HAML:

```
<a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
```

I am not sure how to do that.  Any idea? I am only able to do this:

```
%a.btn
  %span.icon-bar Hello
```

but not sure how to do the complex stuff.

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
%a.btn.btn-navbar{"data-target" => ".nav-collapse", "data-toggle" => "collapse"}
```

**OR Else**

```
%a.btn.btn-navbar{:data => {:toggle => 'collapse', :target => '.nav-collapse'}}
```

Comment: since there's zero ruby going on in this line, it doesn't help readability to use the hash rocket syntax here.

`%a.btn.btn-navbar(data-target=".nav-collapse" data-toggle="collapse")`

is more helpful for nodes which don't have computed attribute values.

Comment: Thanks, @Slomojo! Didn't know that syntax as it´s not in the HAML docs. Provides the best readability.

Comment: It's in the docs, here http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#attributes but is discussed secondary to the ruby hash style. (doesn't have it's own anchor) Just do an in page find of "HTML-style Attributes"

Comment: @Gerry's answer is better; use `(data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse")` when you don't need to evaluate the attributes as Ruby.

Answer (score 9):

Multiple classes can just be [chained together](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#class_and_id__and_):

```
%a.btn.btn-navbar
```

gives:

```
<a class='btn btn-navbar'></a>
```

[Custom data attributes](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#html5_custom_data_attributes) can be specified with a single `:data` hash:

```
%a.btn.btn-navbar{:data => {:toggle => 'collapse', :target => '.nav-collapse'}}
```

gives:

```
<a class='btn btn-navbar' data-target='.nav-collapse' data-toggle='collapse'></a>
```

Comment: +1 for showing how to avoid typing 'data-' for each data attribute!

Answer (score 4):

```
/ 80 characters (Chandrakant's anser):  
%a.btn.btn-navbar{"data-target" => ".nav-collapse", "data-toggle" => "collapse"}

/ 79 characters (Matt's answer):
%a.btn.btn-navbar{:data => {:toggle => 'collapse', :target => '.nav-collapse'}}

/ 69 characters (My fave method):
%a.btn.btn-navbar(data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse")

/ 68 characters (Ruby >= 1.9):
%a.btn.btn-navbar{data: {toggle:"collapse", target:".nav-collapse"}}
```

Comment: character count isn't the measure of all things.

Comment: I know, which is why "My fave method" isn't the lowest character option. However less code to read over your entire code base will often make it faster to read, faster to type and less RSI inducing over your career (although I wasn't measuring key presses). I'm sure somebody will find this information useful. Especially those not aware of the alternative syntaxes available.

Answer (score -1):

```
%a{:class => "btn btn-navbar", :data-toggle => "collapge", :data-target => ".nav-collapse"} Hello
```

Just from reading the HAML website...

http://haml-lang.com/tutorial.html

** I did not test this, I just read it on the website

Comment: Nope this didn't do it.  I got it to render ok with this:             %a.btn.btn-navbar{ :data => {:target => ".nav-collapse" , :toggle => "collapse" } }